How to nest "variable" in GitHub Actions function call?
Observe the following, noting that inputs.root-path is set to env.
- name: DEBUG
  run: |
    set -x
    ls -l repo/${{ inputs.root-path }}/package-lock.json
    echo "HASH: ${{ hashFiles('repo/${{ inputs.root-path }}/package-lock.json') }}"
    echo "HASH: ${{ hashFiles('repo/env/package-lock.json') }}"

Output when run via GHA ubuntu-22.04 runner:
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 474757 Nov 15 16:37 repo/env/package-lock.json
HASH: 
HASH: faedfd4f973187a14d71ddedb368bb5d6b76c22cf03838fe3e5e5a0335b7ab35

Note that the first call to hashFiles does not seem to correctly "intepret" the argument 'repo/${{ inputs.root-path }}/package-lock.json'. Is this "just how it works"? How can I call hashFiles with a variable input?

Inside the expression that's just a string - but you have access to join, for example.

Are you able to expand on that?

You can use the format function.
- name: DEBUG
  run: |
    set -x
    ls -l repo/${{ inputs.root-path }}/package-lock.json
    echo "HASH: ${{ hashFiles(format('repo/{0}/package-lock.json', inputs['root-path'])) }}"

See also:

Nested variable substitution
Use inputs vars inside an expression function like hashFiles

Note: The solution is not tested

Currently, such nesting of expressions is not supported.
However, hashFiles function can be provided its input in different ways e.g.:

By setting an environment variable:

- env:
    FILE: repo/${{ inputs.root-path }}/package-lock.json
  run: echo "${{ hashFiles(env.FILE) }}"


By using * glob pattern if there's only one intermediate directory and only one such file exists depending on your use case:

- run: echo "${{ hashFiles('repo/*/package-lock.json') }}"


By using ** glob pattern for multiple intermediate directories:

- run: echo "${{ hashFiles('repo/**/package-lock.json') }}"


By using format function as answered before:

- run: echo "${{ hashFiles(format('repo/{0}/package-lock.json', inputs.root-path) }}"

or, using an intermediate env var:
- env:
    FILE: ${{ format('repo/{0}/package-lock.json', inputs.root-path) }}
  run: echo "${{ hashFiles(env.FILE) }}"


By using actions/github-script and glob.hashFiles:

- uses: actions/github-script@v7
  id: hash
  with:
    result-encoding: string
    script: return glob.hashFiles('repo/${{ inputs.root-path }}/package-lock.json');

- name: Check
  run: echo "${{ steps.hash.outputs.result }}"

